# Android: Deploy Test Project

Tags: android, testing

I've created a Test project in eclipse to run some tests for one of my android library. I can run it without problems in eclipse on my device. Is it possible to run these tests on other devices without having them connected to eclipse? I want to send the test project apk to other people so they can run the tests on their device.

I think I'd need something like a test runner app that runs the test and displays the result on the device itself. Does anyone know such an app?

Thanks

Comment: why do u need such an app? Yo can pass on the **.apk* file to them and run the app...

Answer (score 0):

```
Is it possible to run these tests on other devices 
without having them connected to eclipse?
```

yes it is!!

just send the tested .apk file to their mobile, install and use app.

no need any test runner app for this, i have checked it.

Comment: Hmm, I've tried that and can install the apk but i'm not able to run. After the installation, the "run" button is grayed out and I have no icon to start it. To clarify, I have an android library project that I test, so I created an android test project, that uses that library and has itself as test target, there is no apk that i can run standalone, they both have no gui